# About LayoutInflater and inflate

Tags: android

I have a TextView component. I want to show the TextView in every Activity, and do not want to write this component in every layout.

```
public class Test extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.alarm);

        LayoutInflater flater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
         View view = flater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_clearbalk, null);
         TextView text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.now_time);

     }
```

now_time is the component which I found. How could I do to let the TextView show in current interface?

Answer (score 1):

You can include this layout in any other layout file with the `<include>` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_clearbalk" />

    ...


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to add include tag to your all layout ,

You can use abstract base class, then extend your all new class from your abstract class,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    public View view;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater flater = LayoutInflater.from(this);        
        view = flater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_clearbalk, null);
        TextView text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.now_time);
        text.setText("bla bla bla");        

    }   

}


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class MainActivity1 extends BaseActivity 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        parent.addView(view);
    }

}



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity2 extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        parent.addView(view);
    }

}


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity3 extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        parent.addView(view);
    }

}
```